# What is the purpose of this line in HashHelpers.GetPrime?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I was digging around in .NET's implementation of Dictionaries, and found one function that I'm curious about: `HashHelpers.GetPrime`.

Most of what it does is quite straightforward, it looks for a prime number above some minimum which is passed to it as a parameter, apparently for the specific purpose of being used as a number of buckets in a hashtable-like structure. But there's one mysterious part:

```
if (HashHelpers.IsPrime(j) && (j - 1) % 101 != 0)
{
    return j;
}
```

What is the purpose of the `(j - 1) % 101 != 0` check? i.e. Why do we apparently want to avoid having a number of buckets which is 1 more than a multiple of 101?

Comment: Interesting question, but might be specific to the point of requiring the author to answer.

Comment: Did you decompile this or download the source? As looking at the source of GetPrime it's different

Comment: Have you tried to take a look at original source code and not to the decompiled one? http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs#422
There are a lot of comments that can help you understand this code ;)

Comment: Thanks above two comments. It looks like the 101 is actually a constant called HashTable.HashPrime. Still not sure what the significance of it is!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [comments](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs) explain it pretty well:

> ‘InitHash’ is basically an implementation of classic DoubleHashing
>   (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing)
>
> 1) The only ‘correctness’ requirement is that the ‘increment’ used to
>   probe    a. Be non-zero   b. Be relatively prime to the table size
>   ‘hashSize’. (This is needed to insure you probe all entries in the
>   table before you ‘wrap’ and visit entries already probed)
>
> 2) Because
>   we choose table sizes to be primes, we just need to insure that the
>   increment is 0 < incr < hashSize
>
> Thus this function would work: Incr = 1 + (seed % (hashSize-1))
>
> While this works well for ‘uniformly distributed’ keys, in practice,
>   non-uniformity is common.  In particular in practice we can see
>   ‘mostly sequential’ where you get long clusters of keys that ‘pack’. 
>   To avoid bad behavior you want it to be the case that the increment is
>   ‘large’ even for ‘small’ values (because small  values tend to happen
>   more in practice). Thus we multiply ‘seed’ by a number that will make
>   these small values bigger (and not hurt large values). **We picked
>   HashPrime (101) because it was prime, and if ‘hashSize-1’ is not a
>   multiple of HashPrime (enforced in GetPrime), then incr has the
>   potential of being every value from 1 to hashSize-1. The choice was
>   largely arbitrary.**

Comment: Thanks, as people suggested it looks like gonig to the source rather than decompiled version was the right thing to do!

Comment: Yup! i have had a couple of experiences where odd behavior was pretty well document in the reference source. Way to go, MSFT..